# Shows Custom tab in salesforce account that data sent from custom portal in Salesforce

Tags: rest-api, community, salesforce1-app, integration

We have an application, where user can login with Salesforce Account. and logging user can send the messages/greetings to his contacts. I want to display those sent messages/greetings in his salesforce account, that will show as Tab like Opportunities, Accounts etc.

How can I do that programmatically ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the answer. We can do this by Web Tab. Please check below link for the reference
[https://www.google.com/search?q=web+tab+in+salesforce&oq=web+tab+in+salesforce&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.2628j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=119&ie=UTF-8](https://www.google.com/search?q=web%20tab%20in%20salesforce&oq=web%20tab%20in%20salesforce&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.2628j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=119&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 0):

Hi does the information get logged in a custom object inside your salesforce org or is it stored outside of salesforce?

Comment: outside of salesforce. any other portal